# Using capacitors to make LED lighted dice

Tags: led, capacitor, diy

I've had this idea for quite a while, as I got the idea from *The Stormlight Archive* book series, in which they have marbles that glow. I have a limited understanding of electronics due to some intro to physics classes in college.

Does this sound like something that would work?

If you connect a capacitor to a resistor such as a small LED, and then in case it in epoxy, but then place it on a inductive charger such as a wireless phone charger, will the capacitor charge and then release light?

Comment: Probably not, inductive chargers require the device to be charged (the phone) to "answer" in a certain way so that the charger "knows" that a device is present. A simple LED + capacitor + resistor circuit cannot " answer" correctly so the charger isn't going to output any significant amount of energy. Also capacitors cannot "charge and release light", charge yes, release light": no.

Comment: You need a coil (inductor) to pick up current from an inductive charger.  The concept could work, though the details could be interesting.

Comment: Rather than a regular Qi or similar charger you'd use a simple(r) coil transmitting at a fixed frequency.

Comment: The problem would be fitting everything into something as small as a die, while also properly weighting it. You can buy pre-made wireless power transfer circuits for a few dollars, but they are relatively large.

Comment: LED's in dice would look really cool and could be possible with some effort. I would put a battery inside the dice and use some type of inductive charging. But  the dice would not be trustworthy. Any weight imbalance in the dice would cause them to not have an even distribution. In other words some numbers will come up more often than others.

Comment: Judging by the size of those LED bouncy balls(~5cm) you might be able to make something about that size that flashes while tumbling.  I imagine balancing it would still be an issue.  If you're up at that size level anyway, maybe you could actually also use wireless power of some sort.  You'd probably need 1 coil per face, each of which would be a challenge for an engineer, they'd need to be positioned reasonably accurately and the control/LEDs would likely have to be in the middle, requiring either transparent gaps between coils or corner/edge lighting or some other compromise.

Comment: If you want the LEDs outside the coils, that increases the airgap the coils work past and likely interferes with their function, and would lead to (I'm guessing) an even larger set of compromises.

Answer (score 2):

> If you connect a capacitor to a resistor such as a small LED, and then in case it in epoxy, but then place it on a inductive charger such as a wireless phone charger, will the capacitor charge and then release light?

Nope.

In order to receive the AC magnetic field emitted by the wireless phone charger, you need a coil. These chargers are basically high frequency transformers, except they're in two pieces with primary coil on one side and secondary coil on the other side, whereas the usual transformer is in one piece with both coils wound on the same magnetic core. But the principle is the same. So, you need a coil.

Also it is likely the wireless charger will go into some sort of powersave mode when there is no phone on it, which means it has a means to detect a phone, so if you want it to turn on, you'll probably have to fake this. For example the Qi wireless charging protocol is pretty involved, charger and device communicate, this needs a microcontroller, etc.

If you want simple, use fluorescent marbles and a "black light" emitter.

If you want LEDs, you could DIY a wireless power transfer solution. If you only need a couple mA to light a LED and don't care about efficiency, it will probably be much simpler than getting a microcontroller to talk to an off the shelf charger.

Answer (score 0):

the dice will need some sort of wireless power receiver to receive the charge.

unfortunately Qi receivers, while inexpensive, seem to be reasonably large
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32898114152.html

[image]

maybe wireless tealights would be a better starting point.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001965026911.html

but still fairly large.